# Div jumps when fixed on high speed scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making an effect for image scrolling but my animation is not so smooth. My main div is jumping when fixed on high speed scrolling. You can see it in action here: http://it-shirts.com/simascroll/

HTML:

```
<div class="gallery-overlay pre-scroll">
    <div class="gallery-overlay-background"></div>
    <div class="gallery-overlay-foreground"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.gallery-overlay {
    width:100%;
    height: 200vh;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.gallery-overlay-background {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-image: url(images/photogr2.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width:100%;

}

.gallery-overlay-foreground {
    background-image: url(images/photogr.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    z-index:100;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:100vh;
}


.pre-scroll .gallery-overlay-background { 
    position:absolute;
}

.on-scroll .gallery-overlay-background {
    position: fixed !important;
}

.post-scroll .gallery-overlay-background {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: auto !important;
    bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

JS:

```
var foreground = document.querySelector('.gallery-overlay-foreground'),
    background = document.querySelector('.gallery-overlay-background'),
    gallery = document.querySelector('.gallery-overlay');

foreground.topPosition = foreground.getBoundingClientRect().top;
background.topPosition = background.getBoundingClientRect().top;
gallery.topPosition = gallery.getBoundingClientRect().top;

var isOnScroll = false; 

window.onscroll = function() {
    var scrolled = window.pageYOffset;
    if (scrolled >= gallery.topPosition) {  
        if (!isOnScroll) {
            $('.gallery-overlay').addClass('on-scroll');
            console.log('func works');
            isOnScroll = true;
        }

        foreground.topPos = foreground.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        background.topPos = background.getBoundingClientRect().top;

        if (foreground.topPos <= background.topPos ) {
            $('.gallery-overlay').addClass('post-scroll');
        }

    }  else {
        // console.log('ELSE');
        $('.gallery-overlay').addClass('pre-scroll');
        $('.gallery-overlay').removeClass('on-scroll');
        $('.gallery-overlay').removeClass('post-scroll');
        isOnScroll = false;
    }
}
```

In my code the div is being fixed only once (it doesn't refix on every window.onscroll event), but it doesn't help.

Comment: **HTML structure** ? `scrolled` is undefined..

Comment: what DIV? I can see no fixed DIV in your page

Comment: I think I saw the middle picture jump...

Comment: what do you need to achieve?

Comment: I've added HTML / CSS and missed var scrolled expression.
I'm trying to achieve a smooth animation without a fixed div jumping on high speed scrolling. 
Exactly like here
http://www.alldayeveryday.com/articles/hannah-guests-leisure-time